# External npm modules with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am somewhat confused right now. Here goes simple entry `main.js` file:

`var _ = require('lodash');`

I have lodash installed in node_modules folder, but it's there for development purposes. I don't to include that in resulting bundle.

`browserify -x lodash -e main.js`

It almost looks like that it works. No error is raised and lodash is not included in bundle. However when I try to load it in the browser, I get **Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '9TlSmm'**. Looking into generated file I see this:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="fu
nction"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Ca
nnot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,functi
on(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports
}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);re
turn s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var _ = require('lodash');

},{"lodash":"9TlSmm"}]},{},[1])
```

I don't understand what is happening here. Why it creates that alias `9TlSmm` for lodash? Isn't it supposed to just ignore this and expect that lodash will be delivered from another file ?

#### Update

Alright, I see the issue. When I run `browserify -r lodash > vendor.js` and look in there, it gets assigned the same designation `9TlSmm`. However thing is, that in my real `vendor.js` I am using lodash from the Bower instead of Npm. So it gets assigned another alias which doesn't match. How to overcome this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got two options in this case:

1) Use npm to install lodash instead of using Bower

2) Use [debowerify](https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify) to transform lodash installed from Bower

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much ended with solution 1) on my own. It was just essentially about referencing the same file path to have it generate same hash for the module. I tried debowerify too, but that failed, because path is different in there.